# Illegal break statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning recursive in javascript. I am trying to develop a simple program which ask user an input and if the input matched with our hardcoded variable. I got the error as:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement
```

```js
var secretWord='javascript';
var output=document.getElementById('output');
function startGame(){

    var valueTry=prompt('what is the word?');

    passValue(secretWord,valueTry);
}

function passValue(a,b){
    if (a==b){
        output.innerHTML='your guessed correct';
       break;  
    }
    var askAgain=prompt('please think again');
    passValue(askAgain,secretWord);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="output"></div> 

   <button type="button" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting error of illegal break statement.Can someone say me where I made the mistake?

Comment: ``break`` is for loops, use ``return;`` instead.

Comment: What you meant was `return` rather than `break`. `break` is only used to break out of compound statements (switch, do-white). On the other hand, `return` is used to terminate the execution of a function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break "The break statement terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement " You're not within a loop, switch, or label statement.  Please refer to the proper documentation before posting questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `break` to break out of for loops or while loops, for example, but not functions. If you want to terminate a function, you use a `return`:

```
function passValue(a,b){
    if (a==b){
        output.innerHTML='your guessed correct';
        return;  
    }
    var askAgain=prompt('please think again');
    passValue(askAgain,secretWord);
}
```